# Given a 3-d Keras tensor, how to set the diagonal of Dimensions 1 and 2 to 1?

Tags: keras

Given a Keras tensor, I would like to replace the diagonal with number 1. This is similar to the numpy function `fill_diagonal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `inputTensor` be the tensor you want to change and `size` be the size of dimensions 1 and 2:

```
#create a diagonal matrix
diag = K.eye(size)

#make it 3D by adding a dummy batch dimension
diag = K.expand_dims(diag,0)

#get a complement for wich complement + diag = ones    
complement = 1 - diag

#annulate the diagonal from the input
noDiagInput = complement * inputTensor    

#add diagonal 1
return noDiagInput + diag
```